# Wordpress update_option doesn't work in plugin

Tags: wordpress

`update_option` or `add_option` don't work in my plugin. I even created completely new plugin to test it. WP recognizes activation function, so everything should be fine. I even tried to include `global $wpdb`. Still no option in my db. Any ideas?

```
function activate_my_plugin() {
  update_option( 'my_plugin_ver', '1.1.1' );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'activate_my_plugin' );
```

I also tried to add my own database table but nothing is done. I'm working on localhost, can it by source of my problem?

Comment: can you show us your plugin structure ? where this code portion is included ?

Comment: It is included in main plugin file called ls-my-plugin.php in directory of the same name. This example is in test plugin (that still doesn't work), in my original one I have structure of WP Plugin Boilerplate.

Comment: can you try addin a values without dots ? update_option( 'my_plugin_ver', '11' ); juste as a test to see

Comment: I tried but still nothing. I really hate when something like this happens, everything says it should work but it doesn't. Weird.

Comment: and you are sure the function is running ?

Comment: After some different tests I think that WP may somehow ignore this function.  Every other hook is ok (I looked up in query monitor). But this doesn't make sense, function is ok, register_activation_hook arguments are ok. I give up for now, I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: so for sure it's the __FILE__ ... try to replace it

Comment: I have used your code to create a custom plugin and it give me result as expected without changing or modifying your code. It is some the wrong you are doing something wrong. How you are testing your code can you let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more tests (thanks Temani Afif and Akshay Shah for guidance) It turned out that code itself is 100% working. Problem was in some error in my WP that was caused either by other plugin or Wamp. I completely reinstalled Wamp and Wordpress (with fresh database) and everything is ok.